# Execute multiple queries at once in Mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to insert information of a big registration form into a Mysql database.
I use multiple tables and use multiple mysql_query commands.

The problem is :
If an error occur in one of queries, the process stops but previous queries have changes the tables!

I want to alter all tables at ones or alter nothing!
How can I do this?

Comment: make a research about "transactions".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is `TRANSACTIONS` assuming you are **not** using `MyISAM` since it does not supports `Transactions`.

The concept of `transactions` is that either all the queries will execute or no query would execute at all.

In simple words `all-or-nothing` is what `Transactions` do

This is a basic example using `mysqli`

```
mysqli_query($conn, "START TRANSACTION");

$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO TABLE1(id) VALUES(2)");
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO TABLE2(id) VALUES(3)");

if ($query1 and $query2) {
   mysqli_query($conn, "COMMIT"); //Commits the current transaction
} else {        
   mysqli_query($conn, "ROLLBACK");//Even if any one of the query fails, the changes will be undone
}
```

**NOTE:** This was just a simple example.It would better if you implement using `try` and `catch` blocks handling then exceptions properly.

Take a look at [PHP DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php)

Comment: `mysqli_query()` requires a connection here. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php - Not sure why this was accepted as posted.

Answer (score 0):

First things first - stop using the `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated in recent versions of PHP and will be removed in the next major release (v7)

I would suggest you learn about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and in particular for your problem at hand, [PDO::beginTransaction](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), [PDO::commit](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) and [PDO::rollback](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php)

Answer (score 0):

As Casimir et Hippolyte said: use transactions. And as Stephen said: don't use a deprecated API. Here's using the mysqli API (as an alternative to PDO):

```
$link = @mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
@mysqli_begin_transaction($link);
$stmt = @mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE table1 SET col1=?, col2=?");
@mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $someString, $someOtherString);
if (@mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    $stmt2 = @mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE table2 SET col3=?, col4=?");
    @mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, 'id', $someInteger, $someDouble);
    if (@mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2)) {
        @mysqli_commit($link);
    } else {
        @mysqli_rollback($link);
    }
} else {
    @mysqli_rollback($link);
}
```

Comment: Putting `@` in front of all your calls is a bad coding practice. None of these should fail but you need to know when they do

Comment: @Machavity I prefer to use my own error messages which I display where I want instead of having ugly lines at the top of the page, including a "Headers already sent" error.

Comment: this is a new programming language called @php